# AWS Application Load Balancer with SSL Certificate and WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-application-load-balancer, web-application-firewall, aws-certificate-manager

i created an architecture for my WebApplication. In Front of my Application which runs on ECS i use an Application Load Balancer configured with an SSL Certificate from Certificate Manager and a Route53 Domain. To secure my ALB i use a WAF associated with my ALB. In my ALB i configured a listener for https and a listener for http, which redirects the traffic to https.

Everything works fine. But i saw that the DNS Name of my Application Load Balancer in the Browser is still available over http and i reach my app over this way through http. How can i deny this connection over the ALB DNS Name or hown can i make it secure? My goal is that all inbound https connections end at the ALB. Then the ALB directs the traffic over http to the Application.

Best regards,
L.J.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect HTTP to HTTPS as explained in AWS docs:

- [How can I redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS using an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/)

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer, but i already configured redirection from http to https in alb listener configuration. But i use a public domain with route53 over which the ALB is accessed. Although i configured redirection, the ALB is still available over http with the DNS Name of ALB

Comment: @BieLac This means that your redirection setup is incorrect.

Comment: thx for your time, i will recheck the redirect configuration :)

Comment: unfortunately i still got the problem that when i browse to the ALB DNS Name the https redirection to my domain doesn't work. I checked my Listener Configuration and it seems right... =/ i attached the listener Configuration maybe this could help [link](https://ibb.co/X2S1yLR) , [link](https://ibb.co/5GVN3Gm)